# Hide a column of a specific Row-Grouped Table in RDLC

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, rdlc, ssrs-grouping

I have a matrix which contains a rowgroup and groups my products based on the Category. I have three categories: Laptops, Tablets, Televisions. My first two categories contain columns i.e. RAM which I don't want to display for the Televisions. Each category is separated by a page break. 
I'm trying to hide the column 'RAM' if the Category name is 'Televisions' but only for the specific page

My structure:

- [Categories]
- [ProductID] [Processor] [RAM] [Colour] [etc]

Desired result:

- [Laptop]
- [125] [Intel Pentium] [250 MB RAM] [Black] [etc]

Desired result:

- [Television]
- [126] [Ix TV processor] [White] [etc]

Current result:

- [Television]
- [126] [Intel Pentium] [*need to hide this*] [White] [etc]

Comment: Are you asking how to hide the value or the column?

Comment: @user3056839 Not just the value, but the whole column under the specific subgroup 'Televisions'. It should appear for Laptops or Tablets

Comment: I don't think that is possible, because you have all this happening inside one tablix. Perhaps if you use a separate tablix for every category, or mask the RAM value with N/A for the Television group? Or possibly keep everything else in the main tablix and have the Television category in its own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to do.  The reason you're having trouble with it is because the matrix column falls outside of the category row-grouping scope.  To hide the entire column, you have to move the category group above it.  The easiest way to do that is to nest your matrix inside of a list control.  Put your Category grouping/page breaks at the List level, and then set your RAM column of the matrix (which is now entirely inside of the category grouping scope since it is inside the list control) visibility based on the value of the Category as follows:

```
=Iif(Fields!Category.Value = "Televisions",True,False)
```

Comment: Here's a link to an article I wrote (using your example..thanks!) to illustrate the step-by-step procedures to achieve this.  http://jaysonseaverbi.blogspot.com/2014/01/column-visibility-based-on-group-value.html